# How many rows have been inserted to sqlite table?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using this code in Python:

```
for ... :
  cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,3))
con.commit()
```

Can I get the value of the number of rows that have been inserted without using `if` statement and testing if the value existed before insert?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to know if a record inserted successfully or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046202/python-how-to-know-if-a-record-inserted-successfully-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get number of rows inserted, `cursor.rowcount` should return the number of rows affected by the last execute ( in this case, number of inserts).