# Python how to know if a record inserted successfully or not

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using Python MySQL Connector, I inserted a record into database, and it was successful. But in Python code, how can I know if it is inserted or not?
My Table does not have a primary key.

```
def insert(params) :
    db_connection = Model.get_db_connection()
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    try :
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `User`(`UID`, `IP`) VALUES(%s,%s);""", (params))
        db_connection.commit()
    except :
        db_connection.rollback()
    Model.close_db(db_connection)
    return result
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [`.rowcount`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) attribute:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `User`(`UID`, `IP`) VALUES(%s,%s);""", params)
print("affected rows = {}".format(cursor.rowcount))
```

> **.rowcount** This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that
>   the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like SELECT) or
>   affected (for DML statements like UPDATE or INSERT). [9]

Comment: One more question @falsetru, I used .rowcount before posting this question. But it threw an error "'int' cannot callable". But now it worked, I really don't know why.

Comment: @GiaDuongDucMinh, Did you call rowcount like method? `.rowcount()`? It is not a method.

Comment: I cannot remember clearly, but maybe I made this mistakem @falsetru.
Thanks!

Comment: This is the ONLY way to know if INSERT IGNORE... inserted or not when inserting into a table whose primary key does not auto-increment. (I know because I just encountered this problem). checking cursor.lastrowid will always be zero in this case. (but when auto-increment is ON, lastrowid will not be zero)

Comment: Note that if you use an UPDATE statement and it just so happens that the data for the row update is already the same as what's already in the database, there will be a *matching* row, but no rows will be *affected*, keeping `.rowcount` at `0`.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary, What's the point of changing quotation mark?

Comment: pep8 guidelines about strings

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes

Comment: @falsetru Ah, well sounds like it's only our company convention, my bad. Learned something new.

Comment: @falsetru I am wondering why this does not work at all: print("rows: " + cursor.rowcount)

Comment: @merlin, You're trying to concatenate int to str. `print("rows: " + str(cursor.rowcount))`, `print("rows: {}".format(cursor.rowcount)`, ....

Comment: Thank you @falsetru That makes sense.

Comment: for UPDATE, even rows data is changed, cursor.rowcount still returns 0

Comment: @UmairAyub, See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id48. ... Most databases will return the total number of rows that were found by the corresponding WHERE clause of the statement. Some databases use a different interpretation for UPDATEs and only return the number of rows that were changed by the UPDATE,  ....